# NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - Laravel Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I need to Display Customer Address when User Select Customer Name (Laravel Application).   Following is my jQuery Code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {  
        $('#customername').change(function() {
            var choice = jQuery(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url:'{{URL('home/getcustomernameaddress')}}',
                type:'POST',
                data : {'id' : choice,'_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}'},
                success : function(response) {
                    alert(response);
                    var json = $.parseJSON(response);
                    $('span#message').html(json.address123);
                    $('span#message1').html(json.address456);
                }
            });
        });
    })
</script>
```

**home/getcustomernameaddress**

```
$data = $_POST;
$getcustomerdatas=DB::table('customers')->where('id', '=', $data["id"])->first();
echo json_encode(array('address123'=>$getcustomerdatas["address1"],'address456'=>$getcustomerdatas["address2"]));
```

**Display Following Error :**

> "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/invoice/home/getcustomernameaddress"

Comment: show you laravel error stack, and your route.php

Comment: Route::post('getcustomernameaddress','Invoice\InvoiceController@getcustomernameaddress');   @Kris Roofe

Comment: try this for pass json response : return response()->json($response);

Comment: some time server cannot handle the request. then it's show 500 internal server error

Comment: check network tab in developer tool and check its output and turn on debug mode of your laravel project to view detailed error report

Comment: Hi, 500 is a generic response when there is an error, but error reporting is disabled.  To find the actual arror you can: 1) turn on error reportingin laravel setting file. 2) have a look a php error log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Json Encode to following

```
json_encode(array('address123'=>$getcustomerdatas->address1,'address456'=>$getcustomerdatas->address2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace below code :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">         </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {  
    $('#customername').change(function() {
        var choice = jQuery(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url:'{{URL('home/getcustomernameaddress')}}',
            type:'POST',
            dataType:'json',
            data : {'id' : choice,'_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}'},
            success : function(response) {
                alert(response);
                var json = $.parseJSON(response);
                $('span#message').html(json.address123);
                $('span#message1').html(json.address456);
            }
        });
    });
})
```

Answer (score -1):

try adding a slash `/`

`url:'{{URL("/home/getcustomernameaddress")}}',`